# Bundler throws uninitialized constant Gem::SilentUI (NameError) error after upgrading to Rubygems 1.5.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I ran `gem update --system` to update to Rubygems 1.5.0 and after every time I run any `bundle` commands I get:

`rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/ui.rb:56: uninitialized constant Gem::SilentUI (NameError)`

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Update to bundler 1.0.10 or above (`gem update bundler`).  The issue is fixed in later versions.

Comment: If you can't update bundler for some reason, you can downgrade rubygems by following instructions here http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/UPGRADING_rdoc.html

Comment: @BaroqueBobcat Downgrade to which version?

Answer (score 6):

If you're a bit vague on what bundler actually is and don't want to learn then the very short answer to the question is:

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: This is the easiest fix, for sure.

Answer (score 2):

This was posted on the issue tracker, by my count, 6 times now.

Here's the one that I've been linking everybody to: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/issue/995

Answer (score 2):

Re: "just Update to bundler 1.0.10." — Note that you **can't** necessarily get the new version simply by doing

```
sudo gem update
```

You'll need to fully uninstall your current bundler, ignore the warnings about the dependencies it breaks, and then re-install it. That fixed my Bundler 1.0.7 and got my system working again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like RubyGems 1.5.0, which just came out today, is incompatible with Bundler 1.0.9.

You'll probably want to downgrade back to RubyGems 1.4 until an update is released for Bundler (which will likely be very, very soon).

**Update:** Bundler 1.0.10 is out now.

Comment: If you do need to downgrade, for whatever reason: http://groups.google.com/group/rails-oceania/browse_thread/thread/4c673ccd0f659875

Answer (score 0):

You can also downgrade Rubygems, however this is less than ideal, but for legacy systems if you need a specific bundler version you will have to do this.

For example on the app I am working on at the moment we are using:

Ruby 1.8.6-p383
RubyGems 1.3.6
Bundler 0.9.26

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're using rvm, you may not be able to upgrade bundler yourself. You may need to upgrade rvm in order to update bundler, since rvm integrates bundler pretty tightly. I got this error, tried to upgrade bundler, couldn't, and upgrading rvm fixed my problem.