# Cannot install Redmine on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

I am trying to get Redmine to install on my MacBook Pro (Lion). I've installed XAMPP. Also, as far as I understand, I've installed all the correct versions of [required software for Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall).

However I cannot get `rake -v` to return expected results. I suspect there maybe gem dependencies which are broken. This is my first attempt at doing anything that has to do something with Ruby.

Is there a way automatically detect and fix gem dependencies.

---

**Update:** Complete dump of what I get when I execute `rake -v`: http://pastebin.com/cuksWp8H

Essentially I keep getting the following:

```
MBP:redmine-1.2.1 username$ rake -v
(in /Users/username/Sites/redmine-1.2.1)
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Users/username/Sites/redmine-1.2.1/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
```

Comment: Shouldn't you go to your redmine directory first?

Comment: @Krule: The whole dump make me exceed the character limit. I've added a link to the dump however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `rake --version` as the `-v` parameter stands for verbose. You notice in your long trace, that it tries to execute the test suite rather than just outputting the version.

Also — and this is most probably the cause for your issues — Redmine currently requires an older version of rubygems. As standed on [RedmineInstall](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall):

> Rails 2.3.11 will fail with RubyGems 1.7.0 or later, stick to previous versions of RubyGems !

And finally, Redmine doesn't use bundler (but ChiliProject does) so any bundler issues or fixes do not apply here.

*Disclosure: I'm a ChiliProject developer.*

Comment: Depends... If you are using [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) by using `rvm rubygems 1.6.2`. If you are using stock Mac Ruby using `sudo gem install rubygems-update -v 1.6.2`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did find the other SO post here that helped me with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523993/how-do-you-downgrade-rubygems/4992974#4992974