# Use multiple versions of rubygems with rvm?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have two projects on my computer:
- An old Rails 2.3 app that needs rubygems 1.6 and won't run under rubygems 1.8;
- A newer app that needs rubygems 1.8 and won't run under rubygems 1.6.

Each project has its own rvm gemset, but I can't figure out how to give them different versions of rubygems itself:

- gem update --system [version] results in gem --version giving the same answer in both;
- rvm gemset [version] has the same result.

How can I run rubygems 1.6.2 in one project and 1.8.11 in the other?

---

**To clarify, here's what I want to do**:

- In directory A, have a .rvmrc with commands that select gemset A and rubygems 1.6.2
- In directory B, have a .rvmrc with commands that select gemset B and rubygems latest
- Have two terminal sessions open at the same time, one in directory A and the other in directory B
- Type "gem --version" in directory A and see "1.6.2"
- Type "gem --version" in directory B and see "1.8.11"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct way is to created different named (-n) installs of the ruby you want installed and name them according to the rubygem version you want such as

```
rvm --install use 1.9.2-nrg186 && rvm rubygems 1.8.6 && gem --list
rvm --install use 1.9.2-nrg1810 && rvm rubygems 1.8.10 && gem --list
```

The reason for this is that you can only have 1 version of rubygems active an any given time. This is also due to the fact that each ruby defines a dependency on a specific rubygems version that version is known or expected to work with (regardless of if it can work with another or not).

This is the expected way to handle the multiple rubygems requirement and to eliminate potential problems. See https://gist.github.com/1273035 for specifics detailing this.

Answer (score 9):

RVM has a new feature for this:

use "rvm rubygems 1.6.2" to select that version of rubygems.

```
 rvm rubygems 1.6.2
```

https://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems/  (see: "RubyGems CLI API" towards the bottom of the page)

http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/e39fc7827d2d22e8

Comment: This does not answer the question, namely how to use a different version of the `gem` executable, not different versions of various gems.

Comment: just realized this as well, and changed my answer

Comment: Looks good. Tested it out and you can place this in a `.rvmrc` file with no trouble.

Comment: @Tilo, thanks very much, but rvm rubygems doesn't let me have two terminal sessions open at the same time with different versions.  I'll check out named rubies, though - that might be just what I need.

Comment: you should also use different gemsets -- so in each terminal session you would use a different gemset and rubygems .. can you try that?
If this doesn't work, i think the best way to make it work is to have a separate UNIX user for running your old Rails App, and have a separate RVM install for that user..

Comment: nope.. doesn't work.. I get this `Installed rubygems 2.0.14 is newer than 1.3.7 provided with installed ruby, skipping installation, use --force to force installation.`