# ZenTest requires RubyGems version ~> 1.8

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, inline

I am trying to install RubyInline on some Ubuntu server:

```
sudo gem1.9.1 install RubyInline
ERROR:  Error installing RubyInline:
        ZenTest requires RubyGems version ~> 1.8


sudo ruby --version
ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [x86_64-linux]
```

What is the cause of this error? I am confused by the 1.8 reference. This should all be Ruby1.9.1. How to resolve this?

Comment: what's the output of `gem1.9.1 --version`?

Comment: sudo gem1.9.1 --version
1.3.5

Comment: It's talking about version 1.8 of *Rubygems*, not version 1.8 of *Ruby*. I'm surprised more people aren't confused by similarly named packages with similar version numbers.

Comment: How can I find out which version of rubygems (not ruby) is installed currently?

Comment: Mei, it's already answered: `gem --version`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `~> 1.8` means "Any version of RubyGems, as long as it's 1.8 or higher, but smaller than 2.0". So `1.8.0`, `1.8.11`, `1.8.100` or `1.9` all match, but the version you have does not.

The `1.9.1` in the `gem` command does not mean RubyGems is at version 1.9.1, but that it's the version that came with the Ruby 1.9.1 install. To find out what version of RubyGems you have, run `gem1.9.1 --version`.

To resolve this, you can either upgrade Rubygems, or install a version of ZenTest that is compatible with the version of Rubygems you have by running `sudo gem1.9.1 install ZenTest --version "< 4.6"` (assuming that ZenTest 4.5 is compatible with your RubyGems)

Comment: This is happening when trying to run an old Rails 3 project. I guess you have to downgrade rubygems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523993/how-do-you-downgrade-rubygems

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is run

```
gem update --system
```

For the long answer, see cypher's post above.

Comment: Hm, this is disabled on Debian type systems.

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot about that.  This is where RVM really starts to shine.  I try to avoid using distribution specific packages wherever possible in favor of using RVM.

Comment: If you get an error, "You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory." like on my Mac OS X you'll need to run this as root, so the command would be `sudo gem update --system`

Comment: @SammyK Better yet, install RVM.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Bundler Documentation](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html):

> The specifier ~> has a special meaning, best shown by example. ~> 2.0.3 is identical to >= 2.0.3 and < 2.1.

So the "~> 1.8" reference means any version of RubyGems < 1.9.

One possible solution would be to write your extension without RubyInline:
    [how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-under-5-minutes](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-under-5-minutes-100.html)

Comment: "So the "~> 1.8" reference means any version of Ruby < 1.9." *Rubygems*, not *Ruby*. Yes, it's confusing having two similarly named things with similar version numbers!

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle update
```

helped for me, it updated ZenTest from 4.6.2 to 4.11.1