# How to revert back to the default Ruby install on Mac OSX Lion Server

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-lion

I did an install of Redmine on my OSX Lion Server following the install guide on the Redmine website. There it told me to update/install some RubyGems. The install of Redmine went fine but the procedure killed my Profile Manager and Wiki Service.

Looking around on the web led me to the Apple Support web page http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4042

Basically it says not to update or install Ruby Gems because it will cause problems but it does not give a solution if you already did update or install any Ruby Gem.

Is there a way to revert back to the default Ruby install on OSX Lion Server (10.7.3) without a complete reinstall of the system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you downgrade rubygems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523993/how-do-you-downgrade-rubygems)

Comment: This is why you use something like [rvm](https://rvm.io/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for a solution for this same exact issue as well.
I'll post anything additional that I find.

So, in addition wikid/collabd not working, I was also seeing gobs of error messages in /var/log/system.log from sandboxd regarding ruby:

```
Apr 17 11:34:07 reddwarf sandboxd[3890] ([3887]): ruby(3887) deny 
   file-read-metadata /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000vm00006x
```

I found a thread in Apple Communities (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3216408?start=0&tstart=0) that showed a possible solution:

> ```
> Can you uninstall the newer version of Rack, 1.2.2?   
>     sudo gem uninstall rack
>     sudo gem install rack --version 1.2.1 
> This is a bug we're aware of.
> ```

I decided to do this since I had originally got mired in this mess after updating ruby.
First off, stop the wiki server...

```
sh-3.2# serveradmin stop wiki
wiki:state = "STOPPED"
```

I found I had multiple versions of rack installed (1.4.1 and 1.3.5), but 1.2.1 did not show as installed, which evidently is the version of this gem that wikid depends on.

```
sh-3.2# gem uninstall rack

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. rack-1.3.5
 2. rack-1.4.1
 3. All versions
> 2
```

I uninstalled both of these, trying to start the wiki server after each was removed. The wiki was still not working up to this point. Then I installed 1.2.1...

```
sh-3.2# gem install rack --version 1.2.1
Successfully installed rack-1.2.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rack-1.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rack-1.2.1...
```

After that, another attempt at starting the wiki...

```
sh-3.2# serveradmin start wiki
wiki:state = "STARTING"
sh-3.2# serveradmin status wiki
wiki:state = "RUNNING"
```

And guess what? It actually worked! My wiki is now functional again.

Comment: Did not work for me... Version 1.2.1 is installed and when I try to uninstall it I get the message:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d rack`