# Can't install ZenTest 4.8.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, zentest

When I try to install ZenTest:

```
gem install ZenTest
```

I get the following error:

> Invalid gemspec in
>   [C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec]:
>   Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]

I tried cleaning up the gems and removing the ZenTest to no avail.

What's wrong?

Comment: you should use Bundler to install gems. http://gembundler.com/

Comment: Bundler gives the same error. I got the error after creating a new rails app.

Comment: hmm, this error looks like version issue with "< 2.1, >= 1.8". The solution is probably changing Gemfile to give the correct version

Comment: also having the same issue, my Gemfile doesn't have any version string in the ZenTest gem, just "gem 'ZenTest'"

Comment: I'm with Jorge here, the gemfile doesn't specify any version.

Comment: try adding the version and bundle install. Something like  gem "ZenTest", "1.8"

Comment: It works with v4.8.3 so I'm going to use that. v4.8.4 has been out for a month so I doubt it's broken and nobody has raised the issue. If anyone has an answer I'd like to know.

Comment: I've just spoken with Ryan Davis, the author of ZenTest. He tells me that this is due to a bug in RubyGems and they're preparing a release that fixes it. In the meantime, downgrade to 4.8.3.

Comment: How to downgrade it to 4.8.3 now i have 4.9.2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've just spoken with Ryan Davis, the author of ZenTest. He tells me that this is due to a bug in RubyGems and they're preparing a release that fixes it.

In the meantime, downgrade to 4.8.3.

Comment: Update your gemfile: gem 'ZenTest', '4.8.3' then bundle update

Comment: As an alternative, you can downgrade your rubygems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523993/how-do-you-downgrade-rubygems/29618803#29618803

Answer (score 3):

Updating rubygems to 1.8.25 seems to fix the problem (https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/issues/28)

Answer (score 1):

to cleanup the gem, move the gemspec file to some other location.

e.g: in ubuntu to cleanup the gem, do

```
sudo mv /var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/ZenTest-4.8.4.gemspec /var/tmp/
```