# Invalid gemspec error in ZenTest. Invalid requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zentest

After installing some testing tools, I keep getting an `Invalid gemspec error` anytime I type a command.  The following error:

```
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/specifications/ZenTest-4.10.1.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]
```

I have tried updating to the latest ZenTest gemfile of 4.11.0 and downgrading to earlier versions with no luck.  I have tried uninstalling them gemfiles and re-installing them using the following procedure:

`$ gem uninstall ZenTest`

`$ sudo gem update --system`

`$ gem install ZenTest`

The warning still comes up.

Why is `["< 3.0, >= 1.8"]` an `Illformed requirement`?  When I have updated to the latest gem files for my program?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488605/cant-install-zentest-4-8-4) potentially related question?

Comment: Didn't see that.  Thank you for pointing that out.  =)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/issues/40) thread on Github, it suggests changing the gemspec line from:

```
["< X.X,>= X.X"] to ["< X.X",">= X.X"]
```

I tested it and it has worked so far.  It makes sense to me that maybe it's a syntax error.  But again, I am learning and am not an expert nor do I have a full grasp on terminology yet.  I don't take credit for this fix as it was the gentleman in the thread I found on GitHub.  Just wanted to share.