# RVM with legacy rails app. Can I set the version of rubygems?

Tags: rubygems, rvm, legacy

I have a client on a legacy version of rails (`2.2.2`) Their environment is running with gem version 1.3.2. When I run `gem -v` on the new legacy gemset I've created with ruby `1.8.7` and rails `2.2.2`, it says the version of gem is `1.8.25`

Is there a way that I can set rubygems to 1.3.2 JUST for my legacy gemset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade/downgrade rubygems by following command:

rvm install rubygems 1.4.2

Have you seen [How do you downgrade rubygems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523993/how-do-you-downgrade-rubygems) ?

Comment: I did not see that, but some of the answers were not as useful or as simple as yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set rubygems version per gemset in RVM1, it might be possible in RVM2 - you can read more about RVM2 here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xW9GeEpLOWPcddDg_hOPvK4oeLxJmU3Q5FiCNT7nTAc/edit?usp=sharing

You can change rubygems for already installed ruby with:

```
rvm rubygems 1.4.2
```

Or specify rubygems version while installing ruby:

```
rvm install ruby-1.8.7 --rubygems 1.4.2
```

Comment: Actually, I just did it. When I switch rubies, I can set a rubygem version for that rubie. When I got back to the previous ruby the original rubygem version works fine.

Comment: you can set version per ruby but not per gemset, this is because rubygems is installed into ruby itself (it is distributed as part of ruby) and it's available in the default `$LOAD_PATH`, making it configurable per `gemset` would require removing it from ruby and allowing installation to `gemset` not ruby